# Prevent process to end by any other application in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a windows service created in c# and i want that no any other application can stop or kill that service process from task manager but i am unable to do that.

Comment: That's not possible. If the process has admin privileges, it *will* be able to kill your process.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only with another service, that constantly checks your main service status and restars/reinstalls your service. That's a way many viruses work)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible by design, see [The arms race between programs and users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx) (emphasis not mine).

> Eventually you have to decide which side wins, and Windows has decided
>   to **keep users in control of their own programs and data**, and **keep
>   administrators in control of their own computer**. So users can kill any
>   process they want (given sufficient privileges), they can stop any
>   program from stealing focus, and they can delete any file they want
>   (again, given sufficient privileges).